# Probem faced when using groupBy()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following (example) DataFrame - df (obtained using rollup function):

```
+----+---------+--------+
|Week|DayofWeek|   count|
+----+---------+--------+
|null|     null|      28|
|  27|     null|      12|
|  27|        1|       1|
|  27|        1|       1|
|  27|        1|       4|
|  27|        2|       6|
|  28|     null|      16|
|  28|        1|       4|
|  28|        1|       1|
|  28|        1|       3|
|  28|        2|       4|
|  28|        2|       2|
|  28|        2|       2|
+----+---------+--------+
```

My expected output (example) dataframe is:

```
+----+---------+--------+
|Week|DayofWeek|   count|
+----+---------+--------+
|null|     null|      28|
|  27|     null|      12|
|  27|        1|       6|
|  27|        2|       6|
|  28|     null|      16|
|  28|        1|       8|
|  28|        2|       8|
+----+---------+--------+
```

I am trying to achieve this by executing this line of code, but it **does not give me my expected output**:

```
df = df.groupBy('Week', 'DayofWeek').agg(F.sum('count')).orderBy(df.Week, df.DayofWeek)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Actual Dataframe before GroupBy:

```
+----+---------+--------+
|Week|DayofWeek|   count|
+----+---------+--------+
|null|     null|19702637|
|  27|     null| 5176492|
|  27|        1|     288|
|  27|        1|     326|
|  27|        1|     688|
|  27|        1|     343|
|  27|        1|     327|
|  27|        1|     784|
|  27|        1|     231|
|  27|        1|    1159|
|  27|        1|     492|
|  27|        1|     217|
|  27|        1|     386|
|  27|        1|     165|
|  27|        1|    2761|
|  27|        1|    3233|
|  27|        1|      81|
|  27|        1|     310|
|  27|        1|     341|
|  27|        1|     248|
+----+---------+--------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Actual Dataframe after GroupBy (which is not my expected dataframe):

```
+----+---------+----------+
|Week|DayofWeek|sum(count)|
+----+---------+----------+
|null|     null|  19702637|
|  27|     null|   5176492|
|  27|        1|   1061084|
|  27|        2|   1356286|
|  27|        3|   1407338|
|  27|        4|   1510112|
|  27|        5|   1585684|
|  27|        6|   1876438|
|  27|        7|   1556042|
|  28|     null|   4877306|
|  28|        1|    918296|
|  28|        2|   1560506|
|  28|        3|   1555056|
|  28|        4|   1502152|
|  28|        5|   1456802|
|  28|        6|   1550272|
|  28|        7|   1211528|
|  29|     null|   5011023|
|  29|        1|   1138154|
|  29|        2|   1337084|
+----+---------+----------+

only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: I tried your code and got exactly your expected output. What did you actually get?

Comment: That is strange, I included my actual output. @mck
Check it out.

Comment: because row [27, null] gives a sum of 5176492 (as shown before and after groupby); but manually summing the sums of [27,1],[27,2],[27,3],[27,4],[27,5],[27,6],[27,7] doesn't add up to 5176492. @mck

Comment: Are you able to recreate my problem? @mck

Comment: you only showed the first 20 rows, so unfortunately I cannot

Comment: Upon further debugging it seems like somehow there have been duplicate rows, because the sum(count) value is required to be exactly the half.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I solved it:

I decided to use groupBy first and then use rollup, unlike the previous scenario (rollup first followed by groupBy). Required refactoring and minor changes in implementation.

But I faced another problem which is that after rollup each non-null row had a duplicate. I used `df.distinct()` , and finally got my expected DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

```py
df_list = []
for (week, day_of_week), sub_df in df.groupby(["Week", "DayofWeek"], dropna=False):
    count = sub_df["count"].sum()
    df_list.append({"Week": week, "DayofWeek": day_of_week, "count": count})
df = pd.DataFrame(df_list)
```

Comment: Restricted from using pandas